# Facebook login not working within Facebook for Android's in-app browser

Tags: android, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've implemented Facebook login using the Facebook JavaScript SDK. It works fine everywhere except from within the Facebook app's built-in browser. There, it seems to just fail silently. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Here is a simple version taken directly from the Facebook docs. It works fine everywhere except  the Facebook in-app browser.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Facebook Login</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <button onclick="login()">LOGIN</button>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '{my-app-id}',
        status     : true,
        xfbml      : true
      });
    };

    var login = function() {
      alert('clicked login');

      FB.login(function(response) {
        alert('it worked!');
      }, {
        scope: 'email'
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For anyone else coming here form google, this is a bug on android 5+, here is the bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1651116428448693/ .

Answer (score 0):

Use the subscribe functions provided by facebook, so your window.fbAsyncInit function will look like this:

```html
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '{my-app-id}',
        status     : true,
        xfbml      : true
      });
      
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        alert('it worked!');
      });
    };
```

**auth.login**
This event is fired when your app first notices the user (in other words, gets a session when it didn't already have a valid one).

**auth.logout**
This event is fired when your app notices that there is no longer a valid user (in other words, it had a session but can no longer validate the current user).

**auth.authResponseChange**
This event is fired for any auth related change as they all affect the session: login, logout, session refresh. Sessions are refreshed over time as long as the user is active with your app.

**auth.statusChange**
Typically you will want to use the auth.authResponseChange event. But in rare cases, you want to distinguish between these three states:

1. Connected
2. Logged into Facebook but not connected with your application
3. Not logged into Facebook at all.

For more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus